# Zerodha raw data to Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am working on project where I want to pull raw data from zerodha to pandas.
I am using selenium with python and facing issue while clicking toggle button which will show raw data.
Please see the code below and let me know the fix for the same.

Version details:
Python 3.12.1
selenium 4.17.2

Zerodha Source code of toggle button:

```
<cq-toggle class="ciq-DT tableview-ui" cq-member="tableView">
<span></span>
<cq-tooltip>Table View</cq-tooltip>
</cq-toggle>
```

Python Code:

```
opts = Options()
#opts.set_headless()
#assert opts.headless  # Operating in headless mode
browser = Firefox(options=opts)
browser.implicitly_wait(3)
browser.get('https://kite.zerodha.com')
url_old=browser.find_element(By.ID,value='userid')
url_old.send_keys('XXXXXX')
url_old=browser.find_element(By.ID,value='password')
url_old.send_keys('XXXXX')
url_old.submit()
time.sleep(10)
browser.get('https://kite.zerodha.com/chart/ext/ciq/BSE/SBIN/128028676')
time.sleep(10)
#element=browser.find_element(By.ID,value='tableview-ui')
browser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,value='ciq-DT tableview-ui').click()
```

Let me know if any additional information is needed.

I tried using class "ciq-DT tableview-ui" with help of findElement to location toggle button and facing below exception :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: ciq-DT tableview-ui;
```

I also tried to identify element By.Class, By.ID, By.XPath  & By.CSS_SELECTOR and had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line

```
browser.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,value='ciq-DT tableview-ui').click()
```

`By.TAG_NAME` expects a single HTML tag name, e.g. DIV or SPAN and you've fed it two CSS class names.

In order to locate the desired element, you can create a CSS selector for

```
<cq-toggle class="ciq-DT tableview-ui" cq-member="tableView">
```

as

```
cq-toggle.ciq-DT.tableview-ui

cq-toggle < the tag name
         .ciq-DT < first class name
                .tableview-ui < second class name
```

The code would look like

```
browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'cq-toggle.ciq-DT.tableview-ui').click()
```

---

If the above doesn't work, try adding a wait

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'cq-toggle.ciq-DT.tableview-ui'))).click()
```

---

You seem to be very new at Selenium so I would suggest you spend some time learning how the different locator types work and what they are looking for. This will help you greatly and speed your script writing.

[Locator strategies in the Selenium docs](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/locators)
[CSS selector W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#overview)
[CSS selectors on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_selectors)
[XPath syntax on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath)

Comment: Yes, I am new to selenium. This still didn't worked for me and throwing below error. Will also learn from given links.

Comment: browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'cq-toggle.ciq-DT.tableview-ui').click()
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: cq-toggle.ciq-DT.tableview-ui; For documentation on this error,

Comment: We can't do anything with that error message because we can't see the page because it's behind a login. You'll have to figure out why it's not found since you provided the HTML for that element. First thing I'd check is if it's inside an IFRAME.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the updated locator but with a wait. Try that and see if that fixes it.